# Using an expression in a PARTITIONED BY definition in Delta Table

Tags: databricks, delta-lake, aws-databricks

Attempting to load data into Databricks using [COPY INTO](https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/spark-sql/language-manual/delta-copy-into.html), I have data in storage (as CSV files) that has the following schema:

```
event_time TIMESTAMP,
aws_region STRING,
event_id STRING,
event_name STRING
```

I wish for the target table to be partitioned by DAY, which should be extracted from the `event_time` column.

However, attempting to use an expression in the `PARTITIONED BY` column yields the following error:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS MY_TABLE (
  event_time TIMESTAMP,
  aws_region STRING,
  event_id STRING,
  event_name STRING
)
PARTITIONED BY(TO_DATE(event_time))
```

> > > java.sql.SQLException: [Databricks]DatabricksJDBCDriver ERROR processing query/statement. Error Code: 0, SQL state: org.apache.hive.service.cli.HiveSQLException: Error running query: [DELTA_OPERATION_NOT_ALLOWED] com.databricks.sql.transaction.tahoe.DeltaAnalysisException: Operation not allowed: `Partitioning by expressions` is not supported for Delta tables

My limitation is that I cannot alter the existing schema, for example by creating a new field:

```
event_date DATE
```

And use that as the partition by column.

Is there any other way to overcome this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use *GENERATED* column like this ([doc](https://docs.databricks.com/sql/language-manual/sql-ref-syntax-ddl-create-table-using.html)):

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS MY_TABLE (
  event_time TIMESTAMP,
  event_date date GENERATED ALWAYS AS (TO_DATE(event_time)),
  aws_region STRING,
  event_id STRING,
  event_name STRING
)
PARTITIONED BY(event_date)
```

You can read more about generated columns in the linked documentation or [here](https://docs.delta.io/latest/delta-batch.html#use-generated-columns).

Comment: I don't wish for the table to create an `event_date` column, as specified in the question. That's part of the limitation.

Comment: you can't use an expression in the `partitioned by`...  Spark needs a column